# convert each integer value of list to string that is under a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Data frame df1:

```py
Group  column
0     [28, 50, 56]
1     [29, 51, 57]
2         [30, 58]
3         [31, 59]
4         [32, 60]
5         [33, 89]
6         [34, 90]
```

let's say `group = 0` in the below code

```py
>>> print(df1.loc[df1.Group==group, 'column']) 

     0    [28, 50, 56] 
    Name: index, dtype: object
```

Goal is to convert each item of this list into a string

```py
    ['28', '50', '56']
```

What I tried so far :

```py
    [str(item) for item in df1.loc[df1.Group==group, 'column'].values]
    Out[14]: ['[28, 50, 56]']

    [str(item) for item in df1.loc[df1.Group==group, 'column']]
    Out[15]: ['[28, 50, 56]']

    [str(item) for item in df1.loc[df1.Group==group, 'column'].to_list()]
    Out[16]: ['[28, 50, 56]']

    [str(item) for item in np.array(df1.loc[df1.Group==group, 'column'])]
    Out[17]: ['[28, 50, 56]']
```

Expected outcome :

```py
    ['28', '50', '56']
```

Comment: Have you tried `pd.to_numeric(df1.loc[df2.Group==group, 'column'])`

Comment: [str(item) for item in df1.loc[df2.Group==group, 'column'].values.to_list()]

Comment: .values convert the panda.Series to numpy.ndarray therefore I receive the error AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_list'

Comment: `df['column'].apply(lambda s: list(map(str, s)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer after question update:

from the first comment bellow, I understand that each row of `column` has a list of values, in that case you can get your list of strings like this:

```
df1.loc[df2.Group==group, 'column'].apply(lambda x: [str(i) for i in x]).tolist()
```

and, let's say you have multiple rows and want a specific one (e.g. the first list):

```
df1.loc[df2.Group==group, 'column'].apply(lambda x: [str(i) for i in x])[0]
```

**some explanation**:
The `apply` will iterate through all the values and you can then do a for loop inside and convert all entries to `str`. The `tolist` just converts the resulting object to a list. If you just want a specific entry, you don't need to the `tolist`.

## First answer:

if you want to convert each row list of strings the best way is:

```
df1.loc[df2.Group==group, 'column'].astype(str).tolist()
```

Comment: It still gives the same output df1.loc[df2.Group==Group, 'index'].astype(str).tolist()
Out[30]: ['[28, 50, 56]']

Comment: ok, that's because each cell is a list.. could you please update the question with an example of the input? it works fine in this example: `a = pd.DataFrame({'x': [2, 5, 10, 15, 17 , 21]})`

Comment: That's right each cell is a list so I need to convert each cell from pandas. Series to a real list, because currently, it is [[28, 50, 56]] so each item, which is [28, 50, 56] converted to string ['[28, 50, 56]']. but that's not what I want I want to strip [[28, 50, 56]] to [28, 50, 56] and convert each item to string ['28', '50', '56']

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This solution worked df1.loc[df2.Group==group, 'column'].apply(lambda x: [str(i) for i in x]).tolist() returned [['28', '50', '56']]

Answer (score 0):

Pandas series has a [`.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) method which you could use to get your desired series as that type. Please see example from Pandas below:

```
 df.astype('int32')
```

or

```
 df.astype({'column': 'int32'})
```